# Got an offer from HR, replied and never heard back

Tags: professionalism, recruitment, human-resources, hiring, job-security

TL;DR: Got a job offer from higher-ups, HR invited for a call and never responded, even to the reminders.

For the past four years, I have been working remotly part-time as an independent contractor for the company while simultaneously finishing my degree. In December, I quit the company with the goal to complete the studies faster. The company supported the decision, with hope to have me employed on a full-time basis. I finalized the requirements for the degree and got certification 20 days ago.

Throughout this time I was in touch with the manager and did some minor support/dev work them. About a 1.5 month ago, the local director offered me a better position at the company. I accepted the offer and got mail from HR director (who started in December) asking to schedule a phone call to go over the details. Because we are situated in different time zones (and everyone's busy schedules), it is expected to setup/confirm date via email first, sometimes weeks in advance. I replied on the same day, sent reminders (after five and nine days), but haven't heard from HR ever since.

In parallel to this, the manager I was in contact with quit, cutting the "informal" source of information. I don't want to undermine HR and contact the local director right away, but I don't want to be at their mercy either. Having said that, the situation gives me very little promise in the work culture and makes me feel that I should reconsider the offer.

I am unsure how to react, on the one hand, I verbally confirmed the offer, and on another hand, the negligence of HR department worries me about the stability of the company as indicative by manager leave.

Comment: It sounds like the company is barely hanging there. It is possible they didn't contact you because they cannot afford you. It might be safer to continue looking elsewhere

Answer (score 2):

Since they aren't responding by email and you are waiting on confirmation from them, you could try calling them. An email can be missed or forgotten - somebody waiting on the end of a phone line forces a more immediate response.